# Why after upgrading to Jasper 6.2.1 do I get Null Pointer Exception for LicenseManager

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

In our application, we were using Jasper 5.0 and now upgraded to 6.2.1 and after upgrading when I try to display reports in my application, I am facing Null pointer exception for `LicenseManger.java` class.

I had downloaded jar file from Jasper website and replaced 5.0 jars with 6.2.1 jars. My code compiled successfully and i was able to deploy my services as well.

A snippet of the exception stacktrace is below :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.jaspersoft.ji.license.LicenseManager.getInstance(LicenseManager.java:102)
        at com.jaspersoft.ji.license.JRLicenseProviderAdapter.requireLicense(JRLicenseProviderAdapter.java:75)
        at com.jaspersoft.ji.license.JRLicenseProviderAdapter.requireFeature(JRLicenseProviderAdapter.java:70)
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.license.LicenseManager.requireFeature(LicenseManager.java:113)
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.highcharts.HighChartsUtils.requireHighchartsFeature(HighChartsUtils.java:49)
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.highcharts.charts.ChartFillComponent.<init>(ChartFillComponent.java:109)
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.highcharts.charts.ChartFillGenericElement.<init>(ChartFillGenericElement.java:22)
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.highcharts.charts.ChartFillFactory.toFillComponent(ChartFillFactory.java:39)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillComponentElement.<init>(JRFillComponentElement.java:72)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillObjectFactory.visitComponentElement(JRFillObjectFactory.java:1715)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseComponentElement.visit(JRBaseComponentElement.java:81)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRAbstractObjectFactory.getVisitResult(JRAbstractObjectFactory.java:88)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementGroup.<init>(JRFillElementGroup.java:82)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.<init>(JRFillElementContainer.java:89)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.<init>(JRFillBand.java:121)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillObjectFactory.getBand(JRFillObjectFactory.java:522)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSection.<init>(JRFillSection.java:74)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillObjectFactory.getSection(JRFillObjectFactory.java:498)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.<init>(JRBaseFiller.java:254)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:69)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:57)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createBandReportFiller(JRFiller.java:201)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createReportFiller(JRFiller.java:216)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:85)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:456)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:863)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.jasperreports.AbstractJasperReportsView.doFillReport(AbstractJasperReportsView.java:702)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.jasperreports.AbstractJasperReportsView.fillReport(AbstractJasperReportsView.java:669)
```

Any kind of help regarding this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the professional edition, you might need a new license file. Jasper provides more information on this topic on their homepage (http://www.jaspersoft.com/jrprolicense):

> ### Do you think your license file is not functioning properly?
>
> If you've reached this page due to an unforeseen error with your JasperReports Professional license file, please go to our iReport Forums page at http://community.jaspersoft.com/projects/ireport for tips and guidelines to resolve your issue.

With the professional edition it is also possible to ask this question directly at the support portal. I cannot provide more than one like right now because of my reputation.

If you are using the community edition, it is possible that the component you are using is now part of the professional edition. Please consider looking into the changelog (again, I cannot provide a link).

Comment: I am getting this error with 6.3.0 version of JasperReports. The point to note here is that it works for us on JasperReports Server while compilation fails for only the reports which have Highchart components in them with the same exception stack as mentioned above.
Any suggestions?

Comment: If you are using the professional version (other versions don't need any license files as far as I know) please contact the support.